# Prisoners not Using Phones

Tags: prison-architect

Long story short, my Prisoners' Family need is very high. I have built a phone booth room, but no Prisoners are using it!

[image]

Here is a quote from the [PA Wiki](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Phone_Booth):

> Prisoners will use phone booths during Free Time regardless of what
>   room they're in, so long as the room is not marked Staff Only in the
>   Deployment screen.

There is plenty of Free Time on my Regime, and the Prisoners are all active (elsewhere) during it. Neither the room nor the area around it is Staff Only etc.

**Why are Prisoners not using the Phone Booths?**

Comment: Are the phone boots in a zoned area (e.g. common room), or did you place them in a hallway somewhere without a zone. This was the issue with me, eventually causing me to zone all hallways as a common room. From that point on prisoners started using the phone boots.

Comment: @Sumurai8 No, they're just in a building of their own. I'll try zoning it common room in a bit.

Comment: They also use them in a Yard

Comment: @Sumurai8 That worked! You might want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prisoners only seem to be using items such as phones when they are in a zoned room. To get prisoners to use your phones, simply zone the area with the phones as "Common room".

Comment: Thanks! I zoned the building Common Room and Prisoners instantly started using it. A Gang has already taken control of the room.  :P

Comment: Good. Wait, no. That's not good. Well, glad it worked :)